# Linq to Entities - Create New Database Table from Code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I currently have a Entity model for a program that I am developing. Is it possible to create a new Database table from the Program to MS-SQL ?

Code:

```
  using (var data = new ProjectEntities())

{

 String queryString = @"CREATE TABLE Deadspots
                (
                ID int,
                Time, datetime(350),
                PosY double(350),
                PosX double(350))";

}
```

I did try the ObjectContext.CreateQuery for this though in the .NET documentation example it only gives out a standard query. Or is their a different way to do this ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand` or `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`. However if you create a table like that you won't be able really to use it with EF (i.e. you will only be able to send SQL queries/command you create manually instead of being able to use it in Linq queries etc.). If you want to take advantage of EF features you should consider migrations/initializers if you you are using Code First or create the table in the database and update the edmx accordingly if you are using Database First.